# how to choose Optimized CPM

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I am using the ads api of facebook and I want to set the `optimization & pricing` to `Optimized CPM` and then select `Use Default Bids`.

I need:

```
bid_type=ABSOLUTE_OCPM
```

but what is the value that I have to set in the bid info?

I want Facebook to decide the bid info.

this is the document of `Optimized CMP`:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/optimizedcpm/

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a value in `bid_info` as the API does not allocate one automatically.

The value you set should be the value the advertiser considers each to be worth. In the following example, the advertiser values actions to be worth 500 cents in local currency:

```
"bid_info={'CLICKS':0,'REACH':0,'SOCIAL':0,'ACTIONS':500}"
```